# ActionView::Template::Error: unknown encoding name - undecided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.1

This is probably an easy fix, but my google fu has failed me.
Is there an easy way to find out from this which file has the encoding problem.

The application file has a meta tag for UTF-8
The application controller has a config.encoding ="utf-8"

I don't see any error in the browser. I'm seeing it from rake test.

```
    1) Error:
StoreControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: unknown encoding name - undecided
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:202:in `force_encoding'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:202:in `encode!'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:266:in `compile'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `synchronize'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `compile!'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block in render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `render_with_layout'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:19:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__996699002__process_action__630865188__callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb:17:in `process_with_new_base_test'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:490:in `process'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:54:in `process'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:407:in `get'
    /home/ubuntu/Documents/hartl/depot/test/functional/store_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StoreControllerTest>'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1265:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:458:in `_run__884541456__setup__650240084__callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:940:in `block in _run_suite'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `map'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `_run_suite'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:663:in `block in _run_suites'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `each'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `_run_suites'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `_run_anything'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1092:in `run_tests'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1079:in `block in _run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `each'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `_run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1066:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:780:in `run'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:33:in `run_once'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:371:in `block in autorun'

Finished tests in 0.663328s, 12.0604 tests/s, 15.0755 assertions/s.
8 tests, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

Comment: What files are involved in the test? Of course, you can always just shotgun the problem by running `file -i` against every file in a given directory using a shell script to see what encoding they actually use.

Comment: Shotgunning it worked. Thanks I should have thought of just doing that earlier.